# Preserving jsdoc comments and VS Code intellisense with babel

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, intellisense, jsdoc

I have a javascript library for communicating with server APIS, written in modern ECMAScript.

It is fully documented with JSDoc comments:

```
/**
 *  @class - TODOS API Client class
 */
class todosApi {
    /**
   * Gets Todos, given the parameters
   * @param {number} personId
   * @param {number} [year]
   * @param {number} [month]
   * @param {number} [todoTypeId]
   * @returns {Object} - api response object, data will be array of todos
   */
  fetchTodos = async (....
}
```

When using this API in the unit tests in this project, in Visual Studio code, I have excellent intellisense from these comments, and it's a beautiful thing.

However, this library is used by/referenced in a separate react application created with create-react-app. When I run this through babel to transpile into a format that is consumable by my create-react-app app, it ends up like this:

```
/**
 *  @class - TODOS API Client class
 */
class todosApi {
          _defineProperty(this, "fetchTodos", async (personId, eventYear, eventMonth, todoTypeId) => {
    }
```

And I lose my intellisense for fetchTodos, and actually the class itself because of how it is exported in and index.js file.  babel does have the option to include comments by default, however the class gets a little mangled in transpiling and loses some comments.

Is there any way to transpile and still preserve this intellisense for VS Code?

Comment: Maybe I could import a file with @typedef 's somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use [tsd-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd-jsdoc) to create a types.d.ts file.

In your package.json add a script to run ...

```
jsdoc -r src -t node_modules/tsd-jsdoc/dist -d lib
```

And set `types` to `lib/types.d.js`.

Include that script as part of `prepublishOnly` so it runs before every `npm publish`.

Comment: I'm going to check this out, thanks. I ended up handwriting typescript definition files.

Comment: This is great, but note that you have to manually add `export const ${type}: ${type}` to make it work with Intellisense: https://github.com/englercj/tsd-jsdoc/issues/64